# transform image when it hits the edge of the screen in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I have 10 fireflies that I make "fly" around the screen using the code below.
The code also serves to keep the fireflies on the screen.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *blueArray = [NSArray array];
blueArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue1.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue2.png"], nil];

blue.animationImages = blueArray;
blue.animationDuration = 0.20;
blue.animationRepeatCount = -1;
[blue startAnimating]; 

    bluepos =CGPointMake(2.0, 1.5);
}


-(void) someMethod {
    endingAnimationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.03) target:self selector:@selector(makeFly) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void) makeFly {

    blue.center = CGPointMake(blue.center.x+bluepos.x, blue.center.y+bluepos.y);{
        if(blue.center.x > 480 || blue.center.x <0)
            bluepos.x = -bluepos.x;

        if(blue.center.y > 320 || blue.center.y <0)
            bluepos.y = -bluepos.y;
    }
}
```

The "flying" works great except that when the fireflies hit the edge of the screen and reverse direction to keep them on the screen the firefly image itself is still "facing" the othe direction so it looks like they are flying backwards half the time.

I want to set it up so that when the fireflies hit the edge of the screen they reverse direction AND the image itself is reversed.

I tried this:

In .h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL blueIsFacingRight;
```

In .m

```
 @synthesize blueIsFacingRight;


-(void) makeFly {

    blue.center = CGPointMake(blue.center.x+bluepos.x, blue.center.y+bluepos.y); {
        if(blue.center.x > 480 ) {
            if (blueIsFacingRight == YES) {
                blue.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
                blueIsFacingRight = NO;
            }
            bluepos.x = -bluepos.x;


        }

        if(blue.center.x <0) {
            bluepos.x = -bluepos.x;

            if (blueIsFacingRight == NO) {
                blue.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                blueIsFacingRight = YES;
            }
        }

        if(blue.center.y > 320 )
            bluepos.y = -bluepos.y;

        if( blue.center.y <0)
            bluepos.y = -bluepos.y;
    }
}
```

I thought this would work but the image does not reverse when it hits the "wall"

Can anyone explain why this does not work and if there is a better why to accomplish the effect im looking for?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the transform X value to -1 in both cases. When its facing right you should set transform like this CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

```
blue.center = CGPointMake(blue.center.x+bluepos.x, blue.center.y+bluepos.y); {
if(blue.center.x > 480 ) {
    if (blueIsFacingRight == YES) {
        blue.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
        blueIsFacingRight = NO;
    }
    bluepos.x = -bluepos.x;


}

if(blue.center.x <0) {
    bluepos.x = -bluepos.x;

    if (blueIsFacingRight == NO) {
        blue.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
        blueIsFacingRight = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your right, copy and paste got me on that one. However, fixing that did not solve the problem, the image still doesnt change, see my edit above, the UIImageView is actually an array of images so it looks like the fireflie's wings are flapping would it being an array cause the Transform not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
**blue.transform =CGAffineTransformIdentity;**
```

THe above was in my makeFly method with a bunch of other stuff above where I was reversing the image so I was undoing the change the very next time the method was called ( 0.03 later)

Man I feel stupid